# Error while calling yyin and yyparse from main.c

Tags: c, linker, yacc, lex

hi i recieve the follwing error

```
main.c: undefined reference to yyin
main.c: undefined reference to yyparse
```

this is what i am doing
i have a lex file
a.l
a yacc file
b.y

main.c is :

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int  yyparse();
extern FILE *yyin;
FILE *outFile_p;
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 if(argc<3)
  {
   printf("Please specify the input file & output file\n");
   exit(0);
  }
 FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
 if(!fp)
 {
  printf("couldn't open file for reading\n");
  exit(0);
 }
  outFile_p=fopen(argv[2],"w");
  if(!outFile_p)
  {
   printf("couldn't open temp for writting\n");
   exit(0);
  }
  yyin=fp;
  yyparse();
 fclose(fp);
 fclose(outFile_p);
}
```

before this i have to link :
x.h
and x.c  .

I write following commands on terminal :

```
lex a.l  
yacc -v -d b.y   
gcc -o x.o -c x.c    
gcc -o main.o -c main.c     
gcc -o myexecutable main.o x.o
```

that's when i get this error. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to `#include <iostream.h>` in a C program ...

Comment: It suffices to call `gcc -c foo.c` to get an object file named `foo.o`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to ignore the `.c` files generated by lex and yacc. They're often called `y.tab.c` and `lex.yy.c`, but you better check that yourself. The sequence of calls then should somehow resemble the following:

```
lex a.l  
yacc -v -d b.y
gcc -c y.tab.c
gcc -c lex.yy.c
gcc -c x.c    
gcc -c main.c     
gcc -o myexecutable *.o
```

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out.
add the following to your main.c file:

```
    extern FILE *yyin;
    extern FILE *yyout;
    extern int yyparse(void);
```